# I get this error " No such module 'SwiftyJSON' " after updating xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I updated my Xcode and my previous working app was working but now it keeps giving me this error:

> No such module 'SwiftyJSON'

I tried to remove the import SwiftyJSON line but then it shows more errors because the library is not imported

I am new in swift and i dont know that much, I tried to reinstall SwiftyJSON but then it gives me this error:

> invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

dont know if its related.

NOTE : my app was working before i updated xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to clean the files and copy them to different location and re install pods and after that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

are you using cocoapod or carthage ?

if you are using cocoapod (most of the ios dev use) just open your terminal route to your project dir and enter `pod install` it will add swiftyJSON again better check your xcode and swift version also check the compatible version of swiftyJOSN and the dependency mentioned in podfile.

Comment: their was no need to delete the SwiftyJSON you should have cleaned your project, or just closed or reopen your Xcode.